# How to show a message to user does not has permisson in Angular 2 by guard

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2 guard (canActivate) for authorisation ,
but if user go to the routes for which he does not have the authorisation ta blank screen has come ..

i want to show a message that you don't have permission something like this how it can be possible ?

guardService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate , CanActivate } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class LoginGuardService implements CanActivate,CanDeactivate<any>{

  constructor() { }

  canActivate(){    
    return true;
  }

  canDeactivate(){
    return window.confirm("You have unsaved changes. Still want to leave?");
   }

}
```

routing file

```
{path:'grade-listing' , component:GradeListingComponent ,canActivate:[LoginGuardService]},
```

Comment: Why does `canActivate` always return true?

Comment: It is just checking guard is working or not , definately it comes from the logic true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  canActivate(){
    if(yourcondition == true){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/yourRoutetoErrorHtml']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

something like that?

Comment: I dont want to redirect , i want that user shoud see some message that you dont have permission for this please check with your admin , like this

Comment: hmm something like: ```alert('No Authorization!');``` or you could install material2(https://github.com/angular/material2) and use the snackbar / toast component

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

1) Use the router to navigate them away to a component you have made `error/login-required`. This page would have  a simple html message as required.

See - https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-authentication/ and how they use router.navigate to send the user back to the login page.

2) You could display a modal.

A good, simple, model library - https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal